# How to trigger BSoD with custom error message

Tags: windows

It might sound silly but I want to trigger Blue Screen of Death (BSoD) with custom message.

Is there any script / powershell command / value to edit in regedit?

I just want BSoD with message like `oh noze! It is now blueeeee!`

Thx for any help.

Comment: why? Use this BSOD screensaver: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bluescreen.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue Screen error codes (like IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL) and messages (like "If this is the first time you've seen this message...") are hard-coded. You may be able to manually trigger a pre-defined error (most likely with a bad driver you can write) but you cannot display a custom message.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can do this ,especially without extreme bodgery which will probably break the OS.

The default errors will be stored as strings in one of the windows files, but renaming a string using a resource editor usually makes the file unreadable by the OS.

there will be an app that can make fake but convincing BSODs, however unlike the real thing, mouse or keyboard actions will probably suspend it, a bit like suspending a screen saver.

A  lot of early windows (pre ME/2000) viruses did what youre asking, with fake bsods.